# Identifying the async future sequence

Tags: rust, async-await

I have a future that constantly checking a ffi object and returning the poll state. But the object state is only changing if I called the ffi event loop once.

Example:-

```rust
fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<()>> {
   run_event_loop_once();

   if get_ffi_object().check_status_for_id(self.id) {
     return Poll::Ready(Ok(()));
   }

   return Poll::Pending;
}
```

But if a user executed two futures in parallel, the async executor will run the event loop twice in those two poll method. There is no use of running the same loop twice. Because it will drain the performance of the IO loop. I want to execute it only once in the io loop of async executor (tokio/async-std).

Is there any way to identify the first future? If I added a counter, then it will be increased in each future. So I can not identify the weather if it is the first one.

My expectation is something like below.

```rust
fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<()>> {
   
   if is_first_parallel_future() {
      run_event_loop_once();
   }

   if get_ffi_object().check_status_for_id(self.id) {
     return Poll::Ready(Ok(()));
   }

   return Poll::Pending;
}
```

NOTE: I do not have a control to change the ffi object and ffi event loop. Those are from another third party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any way to identify the sequence of the parallel future. But I could achieve it by wrapping my raw ffi object with a struct that contains an optional id field. Then I could compare it with the futures id. If a future is completed, Then I am resetting the id field.